# Play Framework ebean configuration

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I get this error when I try to save a simple Item to my H2 db:

```
"javax.persistence.PersistenceException: The default EbeanServer has not been defined ? This is normally set via the ebean.datasource.default property. Otherwise it should be registered programatically via registerServer()"
```

my play application.conf file

```
 # Database configuration
    # ~~~~~
    # You can declare as many datasources as you want.
    # By convention, the default datasource is named `efault
    db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
    db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
    db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
    db.default.user=sa
    db.default.password=""

    # JPA configuration
    # ~~~~~
    # You can declare as many Ebean servers as you want.
    # By convention, the default server is named `default`
   jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit  
   ebean.datasource.default=DefaultDS
   ebean.default="models.*"
```

Comment: Did you figure out what the problem was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a JNDI DataSource you need to set:

```
ebean.datasource.factory=jndi
```

And datasource.default as the JNDI DataSource name. You can additionally override ebean.datasource.jndi.prefix which defaults to java:comp/env/jdbc/.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "datasource.default as the JNDI DataSource name"? Do you mean that it should be set like this "db.default.jndiName=datasource.default"?

Answer (score 0):

It often happens when there are not proper *.conf* file. For example I run play framework with command:

```
~/play-2.1.2/play -Dconfig.file=conf/local.conf
```

And I have not *local.conf* file.