# Play 2 - The default EBean server has not been defined

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

Hi I am getting the above error when I attempt to save a Model object. Here are the relevant parts of my Application.conf file:

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~ 
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.user=sa
db.default.password=""

# Ebean configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many Ebean servers as you want.
# By convention, the default server is named `default`
#
ebean.default="models.*"
# ebean.datasource.default=DefaultDS
```

I added the last line myself, but commented it out for the purposes of this, as I have no idea if it's right or not.

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295996/play-framework-ebean-configuration) answer, but I didn't find the answer particularly clear (am I using JNDI, if I'm overriding the prefix, what am I overriding it to?)

Any helps or pointers would be great. I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? How does your model look like?

Comment: In play framework 2.0.x usually the default DB is configured as this
     db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
But you can configure different Data Sources, check this link for more information:
http://www.avaje.org/configure_editproperties.html

Comment: Are you running the save() method as part of a test or in your src?  I was getting the same error just now because I was calling save() before the database was initialized.

Answer (score -1):

Uncomment:
"ebean.datasource.default=DefaultDS"

And verify if your models extend Model and are annotated @Entity.